# How to keep log of all search keywords on Sharepoint 2007 site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-api

We have sharepoint site and we are using sharepoint 2007.
We want to keep track of all search keywords which are used by end users to search any document.
How it could be done.Can we use Sql table to store keyword each time we get hit for document search.
Thanks in advance,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 0):

These are already stored in the IIS log files (or SQL if you chose to setup up IIS logging that way). You simply need to extract the query from the querystring that is associated with your search pages [ i.e: &q=MySearchTerm ]. A regular expression should do the trick nicely.

Answer (score 0):

open central admin then move to your shared services,under search you will find search usage report there you can fine all searched keyworkds.